# Python3.7: Shell restarts whenever I import docx

Tags: python-3.x, shell, python-docx

I'm new to Python.    I just installed module *python-docx* successfully in the command line.     But when I typed "`import docx`" in Shell, Shell always restarts.   Then, when I entered "`docx.Document()`", error occurs as below:

```
NameError: name "docx" is not defined.
```

Why this would happen? How to fix? Thanks!

Plus:   On the top of my Shell, it shows:

**Python 3.7.0a2 (v3.7.0a2:f7ac4fe, Oct 17 2017, 17:06:29) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32**

And, the *lxml module* I first installed is *lxml-4.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64*

But, if Python 3.7 hasn't been released yet, does it mean the version I'm using is just Python 3.7 in development?

Thanks!

Comment: What operating system are you using?  What exactly happens when the shell "restarts"?

Comment: I'm using Win7. Shell "restarts" means:   Shell paused for a few seconds after I typed "import docx", and then: ============= RESTART: Shell =============   As if nothing has been ever imported...

Comment: First of all, is Python 3.7 even released yet? And is that IDLE that's restarting? But yes, all variables are cleared between sessions.

Comment: On the top of my Shell, it shows:     Python 3.7.0a2 (v3.7.0a2:f7ac4fe, Oct 17 2017, 17:06:29) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a significant chance this actually has to do with the lxml module, which `python-docx` is based on. Instead of typing `import docx`, try `import lxml` and see if you get the same behavior. If so, that narrows it down a little and you can search on `lxml shell restart` or similar to get more specific answers.

`lxml` uses a couple of DLLs that may not be installed by default on Windows and that can sometimes cause trouble.

If that doesn't work, you should describe exactly how you installed Python. There are several distributions out there (like Anaconda vs. a "direct" distribution) and that will impact the diagnosis.

In any case, using Python 3.7 is not advisable for a beginner. What you have is an alpha release which won't be final until next June. Better to stick with what's stable, especially while you're learning. If you can uninstall and find a 3.6 version to install it might "just work", and in any case is likely to produce a more useful error message.

Comment: Thanks! I replaced it with Python2.7. And then everything worked!   Thanks so much for your answer!!!

Comment: @BirdPlay6 You should accept this answer if it pointed you in the right direction. That's how the StackOverflow "economy" works, it's the way you reward folks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted the answer by clicking on the Tick! Also, I clicked on "vote up", but the votes didn't change. Maybe this is because my reputation is too low?

Comment: Yes, I believe there's a minimum for voting, although I believe it's pretty low, something less that 20 if I remember correctly :)